# Create Dynamic a Crystal Report with many queries

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

Good night, sorry for my question but I haven't found too much information about it.

I'm designing some reports to my work (for accounting) and I'm forced to use Crystal Reports with VS2005 however I have a problem because I need to use dynamic information, I have two important views the first one give me general data like: Account ID, Account Name, Description, Opening Balance, Charges, Deposits, Ending Balance, Code Month.

In next query I need to use each Account ID because I'll get its Details (if they have data) and it gives information like: Date, Policy ID, Description, Charges, Deposits, Code Month.

My problem is not get information because the DBA gave me both views, my problem is that I don't know how can I add those views in a Crystal Report and show their information Dynamic. Because first query is going to give all general data and with each value I need show their details (if they have). Maybe the next draw could give you and idea what I'm talking. Thank you very much if any of you have any example (not necessary about my topic, just with two queries) I'll be very happy.

http://s30.postimg.org/e84fkimep/test.png

Sorry because I haven't given you any code but I just have those two views and I don't know how to create the dynamic report. I have tried to find information and I couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one option is to link the views in database expert, If this is not possible then use sub report in crystal report where use 1st view in main report and 2nd view in sub report.

Comment: Do you know how can I do a report with at least 11 queries?

Comment: you can do with any number of queries but report performance will effect with usage of more queries.

Answer (score 0):

Link the views and use grouping for accounts. Subreports are an option too but the report will be slower